# Trying to implement Undo/Redo and found this article that I do not quite understand. Help?

Tags: c#, command, design-patterns, undo-redo

In my application there is a multidimensional array with potentially a lot of data so completely saving that object every time the user changes it seems unfeasible.

I read about the Command pattern and eventually found [this](http://mullr.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/trick-hot-command-pattern-in-csharp/) article but I do not quite understand it. I'm not sure about how his code example works and whether or not this will work in my application. Also, is this "new" method preferable to the GoF pattern?

My application has tools like a brush and fill tool that work on the current document and I'm not really sure how to best implement undo/redo functionality but I know saving the state of the object for every operation would not allow for infinite undo's and redo's which is what I'm after. I'm not sure if the Command pattern can be used in this context or whether or not and how the article's implementation works.

Hopefully someone can elaborate upon the article or perhaps explain how the Command pattern could be adapted to my needs. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with three values (location, oldvalue, and newvalue, where location points to an element in your multidimensional array) and two methods (undo, redo). The on each operation, creat an array of these object for each element in your large array that changes, and push it onto an undo stack. When popping off the undo stack, call undo, and then push to a redo stack. Opposite for redo pop. Just remember to clear the redo stack with new actions.

**EDIT:**

Sample:

```
public void undo()
{
    location = oldvalue;
}

public void redo()
{
    location = newvalue;
}
```

And then an example of the stacks:

```
command = undoStack.Pop();
command.undo();
redoStack.Push(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just doing a little research lead me to a few possible solutions. Simplest is probably using a stack. Another is using the memento pattern. But you since you asked about the command pattern here is a simple example.

This is essentially taken from codeprojects example.

```
class Document
{
   private List<string> _textArray = new List<string>();

   public void Write(string text)
   {
       _textArray.Add(text);
   }
   public void Erase(string text)
   {
       _textArray.Remove(text);
   }
   public void Erase(int textLevel)
   {
       _textArray.RemoveAt(textLevel);
   }

   public string ReadDocument()
   {
       System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
       foreach(string text in _textArray)
           sb.Append(text);
       return sb.ToString();
   }
}

abstract class Command
{        
   abstract public void Redo();
   abstract public void Undo();
}

class DocumentEditCommand : Command
{
   private Document _editableDoc;
   private string _text;

   public DocumentEditCommand(Document doc, string text)
   {
       _editableDoc = doc;
       _text = text;
       _editableDoc.Write(_text);
    }
   override public void Redo()
   {
       _editableDoc.Write(_text);
   } 
   override public void Undo()
   {
       _editableDoc.Erase(_text);
   }
}

class DocumentInvoker
{
   private List<Command> _commands = new List<Command>();

   private Document _doc = new Document();

   public void Redo( int level )
   {
       Console.WriteLine( "---- Redo {0} level ", level );
       ((Command)_commands[ level ]).Redo();
   }

   public void Undo( int level )
   {
       Console.WriteLine( "---- Undo {0} level ", level );
       ((Command)_commands[ level ]).Undo();
   }

   public void Write(string text)
   {
       DocumentEditCommand cmd = new 
       DocumentEditCommand(_doc,text);
       _commands.Add(cmd);
   }

   public string Read()
   {
      return _doc.ReadDocument();
   }
}
```

Using the command pattern.

We do two "actions" to the instance of the documentinvoker (implementing our command pattern).

```
DocumentInvoker instance = new DocumentInvoker ();
instance.Write("This is the original text.");
instance.Write(" Here is some other text.");
```

now we can undo those actions.

```
instance.Undo(1);
```

The text in the document will now be.

```
---- Undo 1 level
This is the original text.
```

now we can redo this action

```
instance.Redo(1);
```

The text will be.

```
---- Redo 1 level
This is the original text. Here is some other text.
```

Obviously you'll need to modify this to meet your needs. And if you want a little more explanation check out the article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/DesignPatterns.aspx.